# FREEBSD IPFW - Add/Remove rule

Tags: addition, freebsd, putty, ipfw

Thank you for existing and making my life easier :). I need your help, please.

I need to create a putty function to work like this.

A command in putty:

```
ipfw addip [IP]
```

This will add in /etc/rules.ipfw the following line:

```
$IPF 460 allow all from [IP] to any 22 in
```

A command in putty:

```
ipfw removeip [IP]
```

This will search in /etc/rules.ipfw for the line with specific [IP] and it will remove it.
Example line to be removed

```
$IPF 460 allow all from [IP] to any 22 in
```

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "putty" do you mean the Windows SSH client?

Comment: yes. i have clients that do not know howto use putty do edit a simple file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a shell script for the user to run after connecting to the server with PuTTY. `ipfw_addip` to do this:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "\$IPF 460 allow all from $1 to any 22 in" >> /etc/ipfw.rules
```

and `ipfw_removeip`:

```
#! /bin/sh
grep -v "allow all from $1" /etc/ipfw.rules > /tmp/ipfw.$$
mv /tmp/ipfw.$$ /etc/ipfw.rules
```

Those are very simplistic examples, and in a production environment should make more sanity checks, but they may help you get started.

Comment: its perfect. thank you for your time. can you please be more specific for sanitization checks? give example if possible, thank you.

Comment: Sure. For example, the script should make sure that an argument was passed to it at all, e.g. `if [ $# -ge 1 ] ....`  It should also make sure that the argument actually looks like an IP address.  If an attacker ran this script with an argument like `ipfw_addip "any to any;"` then /etc/ipfw.rules would include `$IPF 460 allow all from any to any; to any 22 in` which would open up the firewall to the entire world.

Comment: thank you so much !!!! now, can i make an command to search within lines ,for example [ ipfw_list 22 ] and i would see just $IPS that have acces to port $22 ? thank you.